# How to increment a Record Field using Scheme define-syntax macro

Tags: macros, scheme, chez-scheme, define-syntax

Given a Chez Scheme record with many numeric fields that are contantly being mutated by small increments and decrements, usually by one, is there a way to write a macro that can mutate a field value by passing it the field? The way I accomplish this now is something like the following REPL transcript:

```lisp
Chez Scheme Version 9.5.4
Copyright 1984-2020 Cisco Systems, Inc.

> (define-record-type r (fields (mutable x) (mutable y)
                                ;; and so on...
                                ))
> (define my-r (make-r 3 5
                       ;; and so on...
                       ))
> (r-x-set! my-r (+ (r-x my-r) 1))
> my-r
#[#{r gak6l6ll8wuv7yd61kiomgudo-2} 4 5]
```

It would be nice to have a simple macro, say `inc!`, that could do the mutating increment/decrement operations on the fields in the record. I started with something like a Scheme version of Lisps `incf` and `decf`,

```lisp
(define-syntax inc!
    (syntax-rules ()
      ((_ x) (begin (set! x (+ x 1)) x))))

(inc! (r-x my-r)) ;; Syntax error
```

Which works for "normal" variables (and makes it easy to implement `dec!`), but it doesn't use the mechanism to set mutable record fields, `r-x-set!` in this case.

Is there an obvious way to write such a macro? One where you can just pass a reference to the record field without having to write something different for each field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a `-set!` mutator from the given accessor. This can be done by converting the symbol for the accessor to a string and appending `"-set!"` to it. Then `eval` can be used to get the actual mutator procedure. Here is a macro that increments a specified field by some amount `n`:

```
(define-syntax increment-n!
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ (acc rec) n)
     (let* ((acc-name (symbol->string (quote acc)))
            (mut-name (string-append acc-name "-set!"))
            (mut! (eval (string->symbol mut-name))))
       (mut! rec (+ (acc rec) n)))]))
```

This can be used to create an `inc!` macro:

```
(define-syntax inc!
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ (acc rec)) (increment-n! (acc rec) 1)]))
```

But, it would be nice to be able to increment multiple fields at the same time; here are `inc!` and `dec!` macros that do that:

```
(define-syntax inc!
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ (acc rec) ...) (begin (increment-n! (acc rec) 1) ...)]))

(define-syntax dec!
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ (acc rec) ...) (begin (increment-n! (acc rec) -1) ...)]))
```

Sample interaction:

```
> my-r
#[#{r n5an6pxs3wvid36v2gvn8z9zo-5} 3 5 7]
> (inc! (r-x my-r))
> my-r
#[#{r n5an6pxs3wvid36v2gvn8z9zo-5} 4 5 7]
> (dec! (r-z my-r))
> my-r
#[#{r n5an6pxs3wvid36v2gvn8z9zo-5} 4 5 6]
> (inc! (r-x my-r) (r-y my-r) (r-z my-r))
> my-r
#[#{r n5an6pxs3wvid36v2gvn8z9zo-5} 5 6 7]
```

---

### A Note on the Use of `eval`

The `increment-n!` macro constructs a symbol which has already been bound to a mutator procedure. That symbol could then be bound to `mut!` directly, but then when the expression `(mut! rec (+ (acc rec) n))` is evaluated an exception would be raised since `mut!` now evaluates to a symbol, e.g., `r-x-set!`. We want `mut!` to evaluate to a procedure in a procedure call. By calling `eval` on the constructed symbol first we get the mutator procedure which is bound to that symbol, binding it to `mut!` instead of the symbol.

Here is a REPL interaction that illustrates the problem, and will hopefully help to clarify:

```
> (define f (string->symbol "+"))
> f
+
> (f 1 2)

Exception: attempt to apply non-procedure +
Type (debug) to enter the debugger.
> (define f (eval (string->symbol "+")))
> f
#<procedure +>
> (f 1 2)
3
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was after. And it is easy to extend to inc/dec by values other than 1. If you have a moment, could you explain why the `eval` is needed when creating the mutator? I know the symbol is not a procedure, but how doe the `eval` fix that?

Comment: @clartaq -- I have added some commentary about that to the end of my answer; let me know if you need some more clarification.

Comment: That's helpful. Thank you for the additional explanation.